# Use differentials to find the approximate price of the commodity

Tags: functions, derivatives, approximation, finance, tangent-line

[image: the task itself]
 I have answered part a: P=3.093, Q=1031.882. 
I understand that in b I need a linear approximation, but I can't think of one. For what function do I need to write it? For supply or for demand? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need it for both!  Using the first equation, what is the derivative of Q with respect to P at the (P, Q) equilibrium values?  So what is the linear approximation of Q?  Using the second equation, what is the derivative of P with respect to Q at the (P, Q) equilibrium values?  So what is the linear approximation of P?

Comment: Qs=322.028(P-3.093)+1031.882

Comment: Qd=-229.965(P-3.093)+1031.882

Comment: And what should I do next&